# Laravel - Any better way to return view page without using ->with() in all function in controller?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-7

For example, as shows in sample code below, I want to return the view page, with include all details of the login user. The reason is there is a nav bar on top and need to load the login user profile image and username. So, instead of using ->with() in every return route, any other better method?

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('users.index')->with('user', auth()->user());
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        return view('users.edit')->with('user', auth()->user());
    }
}
```

Comment: in your blade file. you can call auth()->user() too. so no need to pass user from view

Comment: You can also use `auth()->user()` in the view file. You don't have to pass it every time.

Comment: View composers? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just User object, you may store it in config once and use that from view everytime. Nevertheless, it is not recommended. If with() is the issue, alternate is compact().